# setDefaultViewContainerRef' does not exist on type MdlSnackbarService

Tags: angular, angular2-mdl

I'm new in Angular. So I want to use the  Snackbar from Angular Material Design Lite in my Project. I generated the Project with Angular-CLI and added MdlModule  to my MgModule imports.
i Just copy the code from the doc and get this error:

> Property 'setDefaultViewContainerRef' does not exist on type 'MdlSnackbarService'.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the docu (will be fixed soon). Please refer to this page for instructions: https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl/wiki/How-to-use-the-MdlDialogService

you need to do this setup step in your root app component:

```
constructor(
    private dilalogOuletService: MdlDialogOutletService,
    private viewConatinerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.dilalogOuletService.setDefaultViewContainerRef(this.viewConatinerRef);
}
```